# Pasar una matriz de String a Int y sumar sus propios valores fila por fila

Tags: java

Soy nuevo en esto de Java. Tengo una matriz de tipo `String` del siguiente formato:

```
Mara,10,10,10,10,10,10,10  
Mare,10,10,10,10,10,10,10  
Mari,10,10,10,10,10,10,10  
Maro,10,10,10,10,10,10,10  
Maru,10,10,10,10,10,10,10
```

El código que tengo para recorrerlo es el siguiente:

```
for (int x=0; x < info.length; x++){
    System.out.print("Registro número " + (x+1) + " "+ info[x][0] +":  ");
    for (int y=1; y < info[x].length; y++){
        System.out.print(info[x][y] +"\t");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");  
}
```

Lo que me arroja el siguiente resultado:

```
Registro número 1 Mara:  10 10  10  10  10  10  10  
Registro número 2 Mare:  10 10  10  10  10  10  10  
Registro número 3 Mari:  8  10  10  10  10  10  10  
Registro número 4 Maro:  10 10  10  10  10  10  10  
Registro número 5 Maru:  10 10  10  10  4   10  10  
Registro número 6 alberto:  10  10  10  1   10  10  10
```

Ahora bien, cambio la matriz de `String` a `Integer` con el siguiente código (omito la columna "cero" que es donde están escritos los nombres, inicializando "y" en 1)

```
for (int x=0; x < info.length; x++){  
System.out.print("Registro número " + (x+1) + " "+ info[x][0] +":  ");  
for (int y=1; y < info[x].length; y++){  
int numEntero = Integer.parseInt(info[x][y]);  
System.out.print(numEntero +"\t");  
System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Arrojando el siguiente resultado:

```
Registro número 1 Mara:  10 10  10  10  10  10  10  
Registro número 2 Mare:  10 10  10  10  10  10  10  
Registro número 3 Mari:  8  10  10  10  10  10  10  
Registro número 4 Maro:  10 10  10  10  10  10  10  
Registro número 5 Maru:  10 10  10  10  4   10  10  
Registro número 6 alberto:  10  10  10  1   10  10  10
```

Ahora bien ¿Cómo sumo las filas de tal modo que sepa cuál es la calificación final de *Mara* por ejemplo?

Es decir debo sumar `info[0][1] + info[0][2].... + info[0][7]`
Es decir debo sumar `info[1][1] + info[1][2].... + info[1][7]`
etc.

Y me arroje algo como esto:

```
Registro número 1 Mara:  70     
Registro número 2 Mare:  70  
Registro número 3 Mari:  68  
(así hasta cubrir el total de filas de la matriz)
```

Alguien podria ayudarme please.

Comment: El arreglo de llama info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ocupas que una variable este sumando todo por fila, intenta con la siguiente modificación:

```
for (int x=0; x < info.length; x++){  
   System.out.print("Registro número " + (x+1) + " "+ info[x][0] +":  "); 
   int t=0; 
   for (int y=1; y < info[x].length; y++)
   {  
      int numEntero = Integer.parseInt(info[x][y]);  
      System.out.print(numEntero +"\t");
      t=t+numEntero;  
   }
   System.out.print(t+"\t");
   System.out.print("\n");   
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu apoyo. Así pude resolverlo :)